# How to issue a GET request with jQuery/ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, rest, angularjs

I am trying to load data from a mongodb database, running on mongolab. The documentation is very good but it is weird how there are examples for PUT and POST yet there is nothing about GET:

https://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-REST-API-for-MongoDB

Could anyone show me how to load data using REST to an object? Assuming the query in the url will always return single document or no documents.

I suppose it is something like this:

```
  $scope.getDocument = function() {
    // alert("called");
    $.ajax( { url: "MY QUERY",
     data:  //????????
     type: "GET",
     contentType: "application/json" } );
  };
```

Would anybody be able to direct me?

EDIT: I now have this and it kinda works, but apparently my return is "[object Object]" - how to get meaningful data from this?

```
$scope.getDocument = function() {
  $.ajax( { url: "MY QUERY",
  type: "GET",
  success: function(data){
         alert(data);
       }
     }
     );
  };
```

EDIT2: Now I have this but for some reason I am not able to extract fields from JSON:

```
  $scope.getDocument = function() {
    // alert("called");
    $.ajax( { url: "MY QUERY",
     type: "GET",
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data){
         $scope.userId=data.userid; // THIS DOES NOT WORK
         $scope.foo=true; // THIS DOES

       }
     }
 );
 };
```

Comment: Read about https://github.com/fatiherikli/kule, I found it useful.

Comment: I am writing a client sided app though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET requests doesn't send data to the server, that's why the `data` field of your ajax call settings are ignored.

The alert message gives you `[object Object]` because that is the standard `toString` implementation of `Object`. If you want to see what the server is returning use `console.log(data)`, if the server returned a JSON you'll see it on the development console.

Also if you use any web dev tool (like Developer Console of Chrome/Firefox/Safari) you can inspect the network calls that your JavaScript code is doing, in that way you can see the details of the request and response that you are getting.

If you don't know how to open the Developer Console, on Chrome: click on the menu button -> Tools -> Developer tools. Then in the developer tools window go to the Network tab and reload your page to see the requests.

BTW: to see only AJAX calls in the Network tab, use the XHR filter at the bottom (it means XMLHttpRequest which is the object used to do ajax calls). If you use Firefox+Firebug the steps are similar. If you use IE.. you have a dev console too, but at least in IE8 is too rudimentary, so better to use some webkit browser or firefox.

Comment: Would you be able to direct me to some way of extracting fields from the data that I get from db and assigning them to variables? Your post is super helpful, thank you!

Comment: data is an object, so you access to it like any object: `data.field`.
`console.log(data)` shows a dump of all the object fields (in Chrome/Firefox you even can expand it and "navigate" from the console). Using JSON.stringify -like in the other answer- will give you similar info (but is not necessary... at least in Chrome/Firefox). Also to see the request/response details click on it in the Network panel, it will help you a lot with debugging.

Comment: another trick more... you can put the "debugger" keyword to stop your app and inspect variables, just add it in your success call back, and open developer tools. The execution will stop when "debugger" is hit and you can inspect all the variables there.

Comment: Unfortunately when I write `console.log(data)` what I get is `ReferenceError: data is not defined`. I use angularjs so all variables are inside controller "class" (?). When I added this line to success part: `$scope.userId=data.userid;` unfortunately nothing happens. The json object that I'm loading has "userid" field. I want to assign value under that field to the "userId" variable.

Comment: I based the response in your example :) (where data is defined as an argument of the success function). Since I don't have enough details to help you with this error... try the `debugger` keyword or a breakpoint, ie: `debugger; $scope.userId=/*...*/`, then you can inspect all the context using the debugger. For more help on debugging see: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging

Comment: Is that a proper way of assigning the data to variables though? variable = data.nameOfTheFieldInJson?

Comment: Yes that is the proper way. "JSON" are just JavaScript objects without functions, so in code they are like any other object. What can happen is that jQuery tries to automatically convert the response type, depending on the contentType/dataType of your AJAX call, you can get a String instead of an Object (that is not your case). In case that you get a String: set the correct $.ajax dataType OR you use JSON.parse

Comment: Thanks so much :) If I can ask last question and then I will leave you to your things: what is the "correct" dataType? Because the assignments do not work in my case :(

Comment: If you get a `ReferenceError` is not the data type. You get that error because `data` is not defined (your code is not like the one in the example... check that the success function is `function (data) {..`. If you are worried about dataType... try with `$.getJSON` (search for it on jQuery docs), or use `dataType: 'json'` in your `$.ajax` settings.

Comment: I meant I can't assign the values, I have now reflected it in the question text. I dont get any errors when trying to assign, it just does not assign them.

Comment: Do a dump of `data` using `console.log` or inspect it with the debugger. If you use `data.inexistentField`, you don't get an error but an `undefined` value. There is a good chance that you made some mistake in the field name, like `userid` instead of `userId`.

Comment: But data is not a global variable in my program. It only appears there in that ajax call. I dont assign data to anything. From what I understand data is only the content of return from the GET call and I only use it in success part of the ajax call to extract fields from it and them to my global variables. Assigning values to global variables works in success call as proven by `$scope.foo=true;` which does update, but extraction of fields from json does not work as `$scope.userID=data.username` does not do anything.

Comment: I got it, it was because return of the query was an array. Thank you for excellent help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it could be very similar to your code. You should add success callback to manage the response:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'your url',
 type: 'get',
 // you can use data to include url path parameters. For example:
 // data: {pageIndex: 1, pageSize: 5},
 contentType: 'application/json',
 // This is the key
 success: function(data, response, xhr){
   // data variable should contain your info. You can inspect the fields:
   console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
 }
});
```

For more info about callback parameters, you can check [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)